# Radio buttons don't toggle properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a page that has a pair of radio buttons for Yes & No. If Yes is clicked I want to display a particular div (class="green") and if No is clicked, display a different div (class="blue").  It's a Coldfusion page using Jquery and Twitter bootstrap.  The page is at http://dev.taxtalent.com/employers/post-a-tax-job-new?adtype=Basic. The radio buttons in question are near the bottom of the page (Are you a current member? ). The excerpt of the code in question is;

```
     <style>

        .boxA{
            <cfif current_member_flag NEQ "true">display: none;</cfif>
        }.boxB{
            <cfif signup_member_flag NEQ "true">display: none;</cfif>
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery('#current_member').click(function(){
                jQuery(".green").toggle();
                jQuery(".blue").toggle();
            });
    });
</script>

<div style="font-weight:bold; " align="left">
    Are you a current member?
</div>
    <table width="100%"  valign="top">  
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="radio" name="current_member" id="current_member" value="login" /> Yes 
            <input type="radio" name="current_member" id="current_member" value="signup" /> No
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as ColdFusion?

Comment: This is nothing to do with ColdFusion (or even CFML). It's a mark-up / JS question. Untagging

Answer (score 2):

The "id" attribute of an HTML element has to be unique to the page. You have two different  elements that both have the same id. So the click handler that you have defined is only being called when the "Yes" input is clicked. Instead, define your click handler like this:

```
jQuery("input[name='current_member']").click(function(){ ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Few issue with your code which are fixed here.

http://jsfiddle.net/tk622pua/

**Html**

```
<div style="font-weight:bold; " align="left">
    Are you a current member?
</div>
    <table width="100%"  valign="top">  
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="radio" name="group" id="yes" value="login" /> Yes 
            <input type="radio" name="group" id="no" value="signup" /> No
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<div style="display:none" class="divClass" id="green">
    green
</div>
<div style="display:none" class="divClass" id="blue">
    blue
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input[name='group']").change(function(){
        $(".divClass").hide()
        if($(this).attr('id') == "yes"){
            $("#green").show()
        }else{
            $("#blue").show()
        }
    });
});
```

You can't have 2 elements have the same Id. Id's are unique. You need to group the radio buttons with the name as I did below. As for the jquery you can use the `hide` and `show` calls to display the divs.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
$("input[name='group']").click(function(){

I tried both change and click

Comment: Put your code into a jsfiddle. I cant fix it better from that.

Comment: Boy, something happened and the page has gone south.  Errors I don't even understand.  Bear with me while I try to unravel it.

Comment: I seem to have a jQuery problem I don't understand.  But, for the time being, I have a jsFiddle for testing but I don't get any errors.  It just doesn't show the divs.  I spec'd jQuery 1.7.2.  That's what's being used on the site.   http://jsfiddle.net/vaughn/j5nupwga/

Comment: @user990016 Very close, its `$(this).val()` not `$(this).value()`.

Comment: I'm still getting Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.  I've updated the js in the fiddle project.  the line of code is;  $("#group").change(function(){

Comment: I have the fiddle working http://jsfiddle.net/tk622pua/6/ but I am still getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".  But the page is still not working for the div toggles.

Comment: You might be including you JS files in the wrong order then. Make sure you Jquery.js file is above your own JS code.

Answer (score 1):

There are few loopholes (bad-practices) in your code.

1. Do not repeat Id's in DOM. Id is said to be identical for the loaded Document, so you should always ensure `No two elements have same Id`.

   `<input type="radio" name="current_member" id="current_member1" value="login" /> Yes 
    <input type="radio" name="current_member" id="current_member2" value="signup" /> No`
2. If you are using radio group, you just need a same name for all the radio inputs and different values for each. Until you want to operate on a specific radio, you should not provide Id (since this is of no use).

   `<input type="radio" name="current_member" value="login" /> Yes 
    <input type="radio" name="current_member" value="signup" /> No`
3. In the jQuery change event, you should fetch the value instead of Id. This is important because if you use a radio plugin in future (like iphone checkbox/radio) it makes use of 'value' rather than id.

   `if($(this).val() == "login")`
4. Suggestion: you can use data attributes to make your code generic. You need not to hardcode the classname & divId which you want to hide/show.

in HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="current_member" value="login" data-show="#green" data-hide=".divContent" /> Yes 
<input type="radio" name="current_member" value="signup" data-show="#blue" data-hide=".divContent" /> No
```

in jQuery:

```
$("input[name='group']").change(function () {
        var divToHide = $(this).data('hide');
        var divToShow = $(this).data('show');
        $(divToHide).hide();
        $(divToShow).show();
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tk622pua/1/

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has already mentioned, the IDs should be unique. But you don't really need them, so just delete the two `id="current_member"`. Then the solution is:

```
$(function(){
  $(":radio[name='current_member']").click(function(){
    var isLogin=this.value==='login';

    $(".green").toggle(isLogin);
    $(".blue").toggle(!isLogin);
  });
});
```